# Vue.js Google Places Autocomplete Error net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED - API V3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-apps-script, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

My Vue.js front end is using `<gmap-autcomplete>` from https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps package. When it loads the module it usually shows the error below. I assumed it is associated to the following tag '<gmap-autocomplete>'. I realized all of google api related functionality stop working.

The following error message:

GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AuthenticationService.Authenticate?1shttps%3A%2F%2Fweburl.com%2F&4s<API_KEY>&callback=*xdc*._lrtnqd&key=<API_KEY>&token=116130 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.  common.js:20

[image: google map script error]

It usually happens when the page is loaded. There were also instances where throw an Idle Timeout error. This usually happens when the vue.js page has successfully loaded but is stops midway of receiving a response for google api.

The API Key is under a valid billing account.